# FAQ chatbot without using QnA maker in Botframework V4

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I've found no answer for the question and no similar question asked. Is it possible for me to build a FAQ bot without using QnA maker in Botframework V4. Is there alternative to QnA maker other than using other NLP AI (unless it is free). Or is it possible to build one by myself without too much work?

Comment: with this question, I hope you like writing regex

Comment: Possible but any suggestion to make it a trainable solution? If purely regex it would only be as accurate as the algorithm allows.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many Q's are in the FAQ, and how varied the questions might be.  Let's say you have just 4 different answers in your FAQ and every question has a different keyword: then you could just have a simple switch statement on `Activity.Text.Contains(keyword)` and return one of the 4 answers based on that.

You could also designed a sort-of *topics tree* with cards and buttons that drill down into the topics, eventually providing an answer to the user's question without them typing the question.

Generally though, a QnA or FAQ Bot is expected to be intelligent and provide answers to varied question texts.  Writing something that understands human language enough to interpret a generalized or varied word sentence, and grasp what exactly is being asked, is no small task.  If it were something a developer could throw together without much work, there would not be paid services with this as a business model.